# Basic logic in MySQL

Tags: mysql, logical-operators

Our current mysql script that connects our Invoicing software to our website updates stock levels and what not, but there is a field in our products table which dictates if the product is visible or not which the script does not address. I want to introduce some IF logic to set the prodvisible column to 1 IF the stock level it's being updated with is > 0.

In my research, it appears that IF's cannot appear outwith functions, sadly something I have no experience of and despite my best efforts I can't get it to work.

The current script we have which works succesfully to update stock levels is as follows...

```
update isc_products p
set
p.prodcurrentinv =[{Level_LessOrderBook}]
where p.prodcode = '[{ItemNumber}]' and p.prodinvtrack=1
--GO;--
update isc_product_variation_combinations pvc
set
pvc.vcstock = [{Level_LessOrderBook}]
where pvc.vcsku='[{ItemNumber}]'
```

I want to integrate something into the first section that does something like the following

```
If [{Level_LessOrderBook}] > 0
p.prodvisible = 1 where  p.prodcode = '[{ItemNumber}]'
ENDIF
```

I don't want it to set the product to invisible if it it's out of stock, just visible if it's in stock.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Solved this elsewhere. Here was the soloution.

update
isc_products p
set
p.prodcurrentinv = [{Level_LessOrderBook}]
p.prodvisible = CASE
WHEN [{Level_LessOrderBook}] > 0 THEN 1
ELSE 0
END
where
p.prodcode = '[{ItemNumber}]'
and p.prodinvtrack = 1
--GO;--
update
isc_product_variation_combinations pvc
set
pvc.vcstock = [{Level_LessOrderBook}]
where
pvc.vcsku='[{ItemNumber}]'

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this without an IF statement:

```
update isc_products p
set p.prodvisible = 1
where p.prodcode = '[{ItemNumber}]'
and [{Level_LessOrderBook}] > 0
```

Or, if you were asking about doing it in one statement:

```
update isc_products p
set
p.prodcurrentinv = [{Level_LessOrderBook}],
p.prodvisible = IF([{Level_LessOrderBook}] > 0, 1, p.prodvisible)
where p.prodcode = '[{ItemNumber}]' and p.prodinvtrack=1
```

Finally, how about this?

```
update
    isc_products p
set
    p.prodcurrentinv = [{Level_LessOrderBook}],
    p.prodvisible = case when [{Level_LessOrderBook}] > 0 then 1 else p.prodvisible end
where
    p.prodcode = '[{ItemNumber}]'
    and p.prodinvtrack = 1
--GO;--
update
    isc_product_variation_combinations pvc
set
    pvc.vcstock = [{Level_LessOrderBook}]
where
    pvc.vcsku='[{ItemNumber}]'
```

I formatted everything in exactly the same way as the rest of your existing script. Are you sure that the column `prodvisible` exists, is spelled correctly, and takes a numeric or bit value?

Comment: I tried the both but no luck. Due to the fact that it's the invoicing program that sends the statement, I can't see any error message that may be produced. What would be the correct way to append the first one you put up onto the end of what I already posted?

Comment: @RichardDownes I added another example for you - does that help?

Comment: That new code updates the stock level correctly, but it didn't update the prodvisible to 1 i'm afraid :( Could it be to do with when the results of each section of the code are output? i.e. will the third section take into account changes made by the first section?

Comment: Even pulling out your script and changing [{ItemNumber}] to the actual item number works if done directly within phpmyadmin so I know what you've typed works, which is what leads me to think that it's not using the correct prodcurrentinv value to decide if it should implement it. I've tried taking off the prodinvtrack to see if it makes a difference (it shouldn't, it meets this condition). Need to wait till the software synchrnoizes again to find out!

Comment: @RichardDownes The third section would see changes made by the first, but I combined them into one all the same. I imagine that this way either nothing will get updated at all or both values will be updated correctly, which may help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: @RichardDownes In that case, I wonder if there is an issue with the way that those template tags are replaced by the system? If you are working in a test environment you could try removing the template tag and instead write something like `1 > 0` for the condition, which should set all of the items being updated to 1 if the real culprit was the template tag.